# LWC Salesforce [Object Object] Error Out : [t[Ln] is not a function]

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I have a data that I am trying to show on LWC
Input is : [numberone=1000, number2=2000,resultHeader=ResultHeader:[body=body:[value1=0001, value2=17]]]
and I am getting error: [t[Ln] is not a function]

My LWC html component looks like :

```
<template for:each={data} for:item="toplevel"><template for:each={toplevel.ResultHeader} for:item="header">
   <template for:each={header.body} for:item="body">
       {body.value1}
   </template></template></template>
```

Comment: You are getting the error because ```ResultHeader``` is not well-formatted as ```JSON```

Comment: Thank YOu so much Klecool, I corrected the Response and is able to get the desired results.